# How can I make this query simpler?

Tags: c++, mysql

I have got several textboxes where user can add a date condition and then he gets the table where `textbox1<year<textbox2 and textbox2<month<textbox3 and textbox4<day<textbox5 and textbox6<hour<textbox7 and textbox8<minute<textbox9`

How to make query simpler (without a lot of IF-ELSE in it)?

```
QString request::date_search(QString type, int y1, int y2, int mon1, int mon2,
                             int d1, int d2, int h1, int h2, int min1, int min2)
{
  QString req = "DATE("+type+") ";
  QString temp;
  if (((y1==0) && (mon1==0) && (d1==0) && (h1==0) && (min1==0)) &&
      ((y2==0) && (mon2==0) && (d2==0) && (h2==0) && (min2==0)))
  {
    return "";
  }

  if ((y1==0) && (mon1==0) && (d1==0) && (h1==0) && (min1==0))
  {
    return req += "= '" + temp.setNum(y2)   + "-" + temp.setNum(mon2) + "-" +
                          temp.setNum(d2)   + "-" + temp.setNum(h2)   + "-" +
                          temp.setNum(min2) + "-" + "0'";
  }
  if ((y2==0) && (mon2==0) && (d2==0) && (h2==0) && (min2==0)) 
  {
    return req += "= '" + temp.setNum(y1)   + "-" + temp.setNum(mon1) + "-" +
                          temp.setNum(d1)   + "-" + temp.setNum(h1)   + "-" +
                          temp.setNum(min1) + "-" + "0'";
  }

  req += "BETWEEN '" + temp.setNum(y2)   + "-" + temp.setNum(mon2) + "-" +
                       temp.setNum(d2)   + "-" + temp.setNum(h2)   + "-" +
                       temp.setNum(min2) + "-" +"0' "
       + "AND" + "'" + temp.setNum(y1)   + "-" + temp.setNum(mon1) + "-" +
                       temp.setNum(d1)   + "-" + temp.setNum(h1)   + "-" +
                       temp.setNum(min1) + "-" + "0'";

  return req;
}
```

It's a function where y1 and etc. are parameters from the textbox.

Comment: what's the application code language?

Comment: It would help if you posted your existing query in it's entirety.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you need to create a function to format a date from the component parts:

```
// Are you sure you don't need colons between hour and minute and second?
// What is the punctuation between the date and the time?
QString request::date_string(int yy, int mo, int dd, int hh, int mi)
{
    QString temp;  // Why?
    return "'" + temp.setNum(yy) + "-" + temp.setNum(mo) + "-" +
                 temp.setNum(dd) + "-" + temp.setNum(hh) + "-" +
                 temp.setNum(mi) + "-" + "0'";
}

QString request::date_search(QString type, int y1, int y2, int mon1, int mon2,
                             int d1, int d2, int h1, int h2, int min1, int min2)
{
  if ((y1 == 0 && mon1 == 0 && d1 == 0 && h1 == 0 && min1 == 0) &&
      (y2 == 0 && mon2 == 0 && d2 == 0 && h2 == 0 && min2 == 0))
      return "";

  QString req = "DATE(" + type + ") ";

  if (y1 == 0 && mon1 == 0 && d1 == 0 && h1 == 0 && min1 == 0)
      return req += "= " + date_string(y2, mon2, d2, h2, min2);
  if (y2 == 0 && mon2 == 0 && d2 == 0 && h2 == 0 && min2 == 0) 
      return req += "= " + date_string(y1, mon1, d1, h1, min1);

  return req += "BETWEEN " + date_string(y2, mon2, d2, h2, min2) +
                " AND "    + date_string(y1, mon1, d1, h1, min1);
}
```

This much is a no-brainer in my view.  I'm not clear why you need the variable `temp`; however, I'm assuming that it is necessary.  I'd be worried about not using colons between the time components of the DATE value.  I'm not sure which separator should be used between the day and the hour (ISO 8601 would use '`T`'; ISO 9075 (SQL) would use a blank '').  You also really don't need so many parentheses in the tests.

However, this is simple C++ coding style; the query behind the scenes cannot be made much simpler.  Note that in the code shown, the value of '`date1`' (created from `y1`, ... `min1`) comes before '`date2`', then the query will return no results.  You also have not shown any validation that the individual components of the dates are valid.